# How many squares in $C_i$ over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ element, and let $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ be an extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$. One of the classical results is, all the elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ are squares in $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ if $m$ is even, and only the half of them are square if $m$ is odd. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ be a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}^*$, we define the following sets

$$C_i= \{\, 1+\alpha^ix \, : \,x \in \mathbb{F}_{q}^*\,  \}  \quad\quad    i \in [1,\cdots,\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}-1],$$
and $C_0=\mathbb{F}_{q}^*$. We can see that the sets $C_i$ form a partition of the group multiplicative $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}^*$.

If $m$ is an odd number, then for $C_0$ half the elements are square and the other half are not square. My question is how many squares there are in $C_i$. More specifically, how many squares are in $C_2$.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: I think the sets $C_i$ form a partition of  $\Bbb{F}_{q^m}\setminus\{1\}$ instead of the multiplicative group, but, whatever, the question is interesting, and potentially rather difficult. Character sums may be a tool giving upper/lower bounds, but I don't see how to do it right away. A busy day for me coming up, so I leave the stage for others to try and solve.

Comment: the definition of $C_0$ is $\mathbb{F}_q^*$. then the sets $C_i$ form a partition of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}^*$. I tried to solve this problem with the Gauss sum but I didn't succeed

Comment: Tom Storer's book, Cyclotomy and Difference Sets, is a good place to look for the relevant theory.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that $C_0$ was defined separately.